i have an error to bulid web app react by blockchain solidity, truffle, ganache, metamask:the solution for frequency error please give me the solutio
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import ManufacturerPage from './ManufacturerPage';
import DistributerPage from './Distributer'; // Assuming you have this component
import RetailerPage from './Retailer'; // Assuming you have this component
import './App.css';
import SupplyChain from './contracts/SupplyChain.json';
const abi = SupplyChain.abi;

function App() {

    // Define the newMessage state and its setter function setNewMessage
    const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('');


  const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
  const [contract, setContract] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
        const init = async () => {
            try { 
                // Check if MetaMask is installed
                if (window.ethereum) {
                    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
                    await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
                    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
                    setAccount(accounts[0]);

                    // Create contract instance
                    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
                    const deployedNetwork = SupplyChain.networks[networkId]; // Updated to SupplyChain
                    const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
                        SupplyChain.abi, // Updated to SupplyChain
                        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
                    );
               setContract(instance);
                    // Fetch the current message
                    const response = await instance.methods.message().call();
                    setMessage(response);
                } else {
                    alert('Please install MetaMask to use this app!');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error initializing the app:", error);
            }
        };

        init();
    }, []);

    const updateMessage = async () => {
        try {
            await contract.methods.updateMessage(newMessage).send({ from: account });
            const updatedMessage = await contract.methods.message().call();
            setMessage(updatedMessage);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error updating the message:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
      <Router> {/* Wrap the app with Router */}
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <div className="logo">FarmToFork</div>
            <nav className="main-nav">
              <div className="nav-item">
                <a href="#" className="login">Log in</a>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="/ManufacturerPage.js">Manufacturer</a></li> {/* Changed to proper route */}
                  <li><a href="/distributor">Distributor</a></li> {/* Changed to proper route */}
                  <li><a href="/retailer">Retailer</a></li> {/* Changed to proper route */}
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div className="nav-item">
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </header>
          
                <Routes>
                    {/* Define routes for each page */}
                    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                    <Route path="/manufacturer" element={<ManufacturerPage />} />
                    <Route path="/distributer" element={<DistributerPage />} />
                    <Route path="/retailer" element={<RetailerPage />} />
                </Routes>

                
                <h1>From Farm To Fork </h1>
                <p>This is your home page. You can customize this page as you like!</p>
                <h2>Current Message from Contract: {message}</h2>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={newMessage}
                    onChange={(e) => setNewMessage(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Enter new message"
                />
                <button onClick={updateMessage}>Update Message</button>
                <h3>Your account: {account || "Please connect your MetaMask account."}</h3>
        
            <ManufacturerPage /> {/* Render the Manufacturer Page */}
       
            {/* Footer Section */}
            <footer className="App-footer">
                <div>
                    <h4>The NaturPak Difference</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News and Insights</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#sustainability">Sustainability</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h4>Services</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#co-manufacturing">Co-Manufacturing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#research">Research and Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ingredient">Ingredient Sourcing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#storage">Storage</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h4>Expertise</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#nutrition">Human Nutrition</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#pet-nutrition">Pet Nutrition</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#soup">Soups, Sauces, Broths</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Email: <a href="mailto:info@FarmToFork.com">info@FarmToFork.com</a></li>
                        <li>Phone: + (966) 581901136</li>
                        <li>Address: Saudi Arabia, Riyadh City, KSU</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="social-media">
                        <a href="#facebook" aria-label="Facebook"><i className="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#twitter" aria-label="Twitter"><i className="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#instagram" aria-label="Instagram"><i className="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="#linkedin" aria-label="LinkedIn"><i className="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

            <div className="App-footer-bottom">
                <p>&copy; FarmToFork 2024</p>
                <a href="#privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  
        </Router>
  
  );
    
}

export default App;


Can you explain the error you get?
